# Getting android view for static class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class, static

Ive been trying to get a class in my android app to be able to post snackbars. The class is a manager for a bluetooth connection, and ive needed to make it static in my main activity to achieve this. For this reason i cant send android context classes to it or store within in, making me unable to get the view needed to make a snackbar. All throughout the bluetooth service class i use the method runOnUiThread(() -> snackbarMsg to try to show snackbars. It used to work when i sent view as a parameter of the constructor, but only for the first time the main screen showed, if i switched activity and back it would stop working, and this also caused a memory leak. Any other way to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Currently code looks like this in main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
//Initialise some static variables needed across the whole program
private static BluetoothService bluetoothService;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
protected static ArrayList<LocationData> locations = new ArrayList<>();
protected static List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
Spinner spinner;
private static boolean doneFirstRun = false;
protected static LocationData selectedLocation = new LocationData();
MainActivity instance = this;

public MainActivity() {
}

/*
TODO: view in bluetooth service causes memory leak
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try{
        if (!doneFirstRun){
            //Getting storage
            readFromFile(MainActivity.this);

            //adding example location
            if (locations.size()==0){
                LocationData spaceRay = new LocationData();
                spaceRay.setName("SpaceRay");
                spaceRay.setLatitude(59.40384);
                spaceRay.setLongitude(17.95228);
                spaceRay.setInclination(-85);
                spaceRay.setDirection(200);
                spaceRay.setAltitude(99990);
                locations.add(spaceRay);
            }

            //Checking and asking for relevant permissions
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN};
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(instance, permissions, 1);
            }

            bluetoothService = new BluetoothService();
            //starting bluetooth networking activity on new thread
            startBluetoothService();

            doneFirstRun = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception exception){
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to do first run through of code: ", exception);
    }
```

...

```
protected void startBluetoothService(){
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "New thread started");
        bluetoothService.run(MainActivity.this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bluetooth service failed: ", e);
        snackbarMsg("Bluetooth service failed");
    }
}
```

and like this is bluetooth_service class:

```
public class BluetoothService extends AppCompatActivity{
private static final String TAG = BluetoothService.class.getSimpleName();
private OutputStream outputStream;
private InputStream inputStream;
private BluetoothSocket socket;
private boolean writing = false;

public BluetoothService(){
}//constructor
```

...

```
//method to show snackbar message at the bottom of the screen
public Runnable snackbarMsg (String msg){
    try {
        View view = findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, msg, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snackbar.show();
    } catch (Exception exception){
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not show snackbar", exception);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Error message looks like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:190)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:809)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:852)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:819)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:261)
at antennalocator.util.BluetoothService.snackbarMsg(BluetoothService.java:204)
at antennalocator.util.BluetoothService.lambda$write$4$antennalocator-util-BluetoothService(BluetoothService.java:159)
at antennalocator.util.BluetoothService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.run(Unknown Source:4)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get around this issue. The way i solved this was by sending the view as a parameter in each method that needed to post snackbars: for example the write method:

```
public void write(String s, View view) {
    if (!writing){
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                writing = true;
                outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
                runOnUiThread(snackbarMsg("Sent data", view));
                lockout(3000);
                writing = false;
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                writing = false;
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data, restarting bluetooth service", exception);
                runOnUiThread(() -> snackbarMsg("Could not send data, restarting bluetooth service", view));
                disconnect();
            }
        }).start();
    } else{
        runOnUiThread(snackbarMsg("Please wait a bit before sending data", view));
    }
}
```

in main:

```
bluetoothService.write(ConvertToString(selectedLocation), findViewById(R.id.btn_connect));
```